# Bring a cronjob back to foreground

Tags: command-line, cron

I've set a cronjob to upgrade my ubuntu in /etc/crontab:

```
0  2    * * 1   root    apt update && apt upgrade -y >> /home/user/upgrade.txt 2>&1
```

Now, in `~/upgrade.txt`, this line is written:

> What do you want to do about modified configuration file grub?

I want it to bring it back to my shell and enter 'Y'. How can i do this?

```
$ ps -ef | grep apt    
root      2488  2484  0 02:00 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c    apt update && apt upgrade -y >> /home/user/upgrade.txt 2>&1    
root      5426  2488  0 02:03 ?        00:00:30 apt upgrade -y    
user      32202 28507  0 13:24 pts/8    00:00:00 grep --color=auto apt
```

telling that upgrade process is waiting for me to enter "Y" or "N", but I don't know how to bring it to my terminal. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: You can't.

You will have to kill the running processes and run them manually from the terminal as:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

or without `sudo` if you already are root.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use reptyr (also in ubuntu repos):
https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr

via 
`reptyr PID` (which you already have)

Comment: Couldn't help me with this problem, but thanks for sharing this perfect program:)